# Possible to Interface With ISA Sound Card?

Tags: audio

Old ISA soundcards like the AdLib and Gravis UltraSound are popular with the retro gaming community and it would be interesting to tinker with them on a Pi. Questions of drivers aside (which are big questions, no doubt), would it be possible to interface an ISA card with the Raspberry Pi and have it work properly?

If so, are there any resources you could point me to in order to learn more about how that could be done?

Comment: It would be difficult to say the least. Aside from building a custom circuit board to hold the ISA card, along with a beefier power supply and the associated support equipment to hold it in place, it would be a LOT easier to just write an emulation driver and output the sound over something more modern or Pi compatible.

Comment: There actually exists such beasts as [usb to isa adapters](http://arstech.com/install/ecom-prodshow/usb2isar.html)! They list support for linux 3.x kernels on arm, just roll up your sleeves!

Comment: Thank you, jogco. I had no idea those existed and it looks like an easy solution. :)